# Python, JSON, Ansible - Sort nested lists in a dictionary

Tags: python, json, ansible

Hello Developer Community!

I would like to ask for some help about the following: I'm trying to develop an Ansible filter plugin to sort items in a dictionary, containing nested lists.

I have the following JSON structure, in an Ansible variable named "**test**"

```
[
    {
        "members": [
            {
                "objectId": "member_object_1"
            },
            {
                "objectId": "member_object_3"
            },
            {
                "objectId": "member_object_4"
            },
            {
                "objectId": "member_object_2"
            }
        ],
        "objectId": "parent_object_2"
    },
    {
        "members": [
            {
                "objectId": "member_object_4"
            },
            {
                "objectId": "member_object_2"
            },
            {
                "objectId": "member_object_3"
            },
            {
                "objectId": "member_object_1"
            }
        ],
        "objectId": "parent_object_1"
    }
]
```

What I would like to achieve is the following: I need to sort the items for both "**objectId**" attributes in both levels.

Expected result:

```
[
    {
        "members": [
            {
                "objectId": "member_object_1"
            },
            {
                "objectId": "member_object_2"
            },
            {
                "objectId": "member_object_3"
            },
            {
                "objectId": "member_object_4"
            }
        ],
        "objectId": "parent_object_1"
    },
    {
        "members": [
            {
                "objectId": "member_object_1"
            },
            {
                "objectId": "member_object_2"
            },
            {
                "objectId": "member_object_3"
            },
            {
                "objectId": "member_object_4"
            }
        ],
        "objectId": "parent_object_2"
    }
]
```

Playbook:

```
      - ansible.builtin.debug:
            msg: "{{ test | sortbysubkey('objectId') }}"
```

Filter plugin:

```
class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'sortbysubkey': self.sortbysubkey,
        }

    def sortbysubkey(self, dict_to_sort, sorting_key):
        return sorted(dict_to_sort, key=lambda item: item[sorting_key])
```

Unfortunately, having this plugin, I'm able to sort my data based on the first level "**objectId**" only, but not for the items with "**objectId**" inside "**members**" list.

Could anyone point me to the right direction how to achieve this? I have tried to check other StackOverflow posts, but with no luck.

Thank You very much in advance for the support!